# Can not receive emails on Apache James email server

Tags: thunderbird, james

I have installed Apache James email server on a windows machine. I am using Firefox Thunderbird as email client.

I could add a new domain mydomain.com by copying the domainlist.xml in conf folder of James server and making it default domain. Further, i could add users into this domain.

My problem is that i can send emails from tuser1@mydomain.com to admin@localhost BUT i can't receive mails on tuser1@mydomain.com.

i tried to copy the lines below in my host file and restart the server,

```
 127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
 mydomain.com    IN    A     127.0.0.1
 mydomain.com    IN    MX    10 mydomain.com
```

This is not helping.

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks,

Vijay Bhore

Comment: When a mail is sent from localhost to tuser1@mydomain.com, it is spooled successfully. The SMTP log show that in this line: "smtpserver: Successfully spooled mail Mail1373493645866-1 from tadmin5@localhost on 127.0.0.1 for [tuser1@mydomain.com]"

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem.

Now, I am using hMailServer as my email server.

I added the domain 'mydomain' and few users under it.

Later i referred this link: http://csns.calstatela.edu/wiki/content/cysun/course_materials/hmailserver

I followed steps 4,5 and 6 in hMailServer Administrator.

I could easily add users in Thunderbird client and send/receive emails.

Thanks,

Vijay Bhore